# jQuery Select array not working

Tags: jquery, html

HTML Code:

```
<select name="code[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="code[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="code[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var codes = $("input[name='code[]']").serializeArray();
alert(codes);
```

Alert is empty why it happening I selected value in all select box. but still, it empty can anyone please help me. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Where do you define the variable `codes`?

Comment: @David lets check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is trying to find inputs.. You should change it to select.

```
var codes = $("select[name='code[]']").serializeArray();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3qdbkx36/

Comment: alert look like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: use console.log like in the fiddle - alert just tostrings' everything (i think) console.log and other console methods are preferable to alerts. use F12 to open the console.

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery selector `input[name='code[]` is wrong, because you are using `select` tags, not `input`. Try changing your jquery code to:

```
var codes = $("select[name='code[]']").serializeArray();
alert(codes);
```

If you want to map the returned objects to their values, you may use `map`:

```
var codes = $("select[name='code[]']").serializeArray().map(function(obj) {
  return obj.value;
});
```

Comment: alert look like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @RushabhShah I've editted that anwser. Maybe that can fit best for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name='code[]']").change(function() {
  var codes = $("select[name='code[]']").serializeArray();
  codes.forEach(function(element) {
  alert(element.value);
});
});
```

```js
$("select[name='code[]']").change(function() {
  var codes = $("select[name='code[]']").serializeArray();
  codes.forEach(function(element) {
  alert(element.value);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="code[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="code[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="code[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```